# Approach for non linear ODE with quadratic derivative.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, nonlinear-system

What is the approach to solve the following nonlinear ODE:

$$\ddot{x}(t) + a(\dot{x}(t))^2+b\dot{x}(t)+kx(t) = 0$$

where $a$ is positive when $\dot{x}<0$ and negative otherwise. I am trying to linearise it without success.

Comment: For me the problem is the non-linear term. I don't see how to solve it. I found this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/520232/oscillator-with-quadratic-drag post, but having \dot(x) in the equations complicates everything...

Comment: The $p^2$ is still not linear.